# Argument for $(a+bi)^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

I found out the modulus for $(a+bi)^2$, which is $$a^2+b^2$$ but I am unable to find the argument.

I found out that $$\theta = \frac{2ab}{(a-b)(a+b)}$$

I don't know how to simplify further! Please help!!!!

Comment: There's nothing left to simplify in the general case: you must apply now $\;arctan\;$ to that expression...

Answer (score 3):

The argument of $(a+bi)^2$ is twice the argument of $a+bi$, since $(re^{i\theta})^2=r^2e^{2i\theta}$.

Answer (score 0):

we can simplify the given complex number as follows
$$\left(a+ib\right)^2=(a^2-b^2)+2iab$$
the modulus is 
$$=\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2}=\sqrt{(a^2-b^2)^2+4a^2b^2}=\sqrt{a^4+b^4+2a^2b^2}=a^2+b^2$$ & the module is given as

Case 1: $(a+ib)^2$ lies in the I-quadrant i.e. $(a^2-b^2)\geq0$ & $ab\geq0$ then argument is
$$\theta=tan^{-1}\left|\frac{4ab}{a^2-b^2}\right|$$
Case 2: $(a+ib)^2$ lies in the II-quadrant i.e. $(a^2-b^2)\leq0$ & $ab\geq0$ then argument is
$$\theta=\pi-tan^{-1}\left|\frac{4ab}{a^2-b^2}\right|$$
Case 3: $(a+ib)^2$ lies in the III-quadrant i.e. $(a^2-b^2)\leq0$ & $ab\leq0$ then argument is
$$\theta=-\left(\pi-tan^{-1}\left|\frac{4ab}{a^2-b^2}\right|\right)$$
Case 4: $(a+ib)^2$ lies in the IV-quadrant i.e. $(a^2-b^2)\geq0$ & $ab\leq0$ then argument is
$$\theta=-tan^{-1}\left|\frac{4ab}{a^2-b^2}\right|$$